# No permitir (cortar/frenar) Login a usuarios Laravel

Tags: laravel, login, controller

estoy empezando con Laravel y es mi primer proyecto, aclaro antes que nada.
La idea es no permitir el ingreso de usuarios que fueron "SUSPENDIDOS", es decir frenar el login, actualmente lo hago en la vista, pero quiero saber si se puede hacer desde algún Controller (por ejemplo LoginController en Laravel 5.5 , u otro controlador).
Lo que hago es lo siguiente, en la vista:

```
    @if(!Auth::guest() && Auth::user()->estado == 'SUSPENDIDO' )
      {{Auth::logout()}}
      <div class="alert alert-danger text-center margen-0 alert-mobile">
        Tu cuenta ha sido suspendida.
      </div>
    @endif
```

Existe una mejor manera, o más eficiente, o más segura de hacerlo???
GRACIAS!

Comment: hola, para no repetir código, te dejo este [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167403/preventing-login-with-laravels-auth) en donde tratan tu problema. Está en ingles pero la respuesta es bien clara. Saludos

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo, y por cierto, en cuanto al comentario anterior de @anonimo , esta es una **pésima** forma, en ningún momento debe ser responsabilidad de la vista manejar los permisos de la aplicación, sería la última parte donde pondría dicha verificación.

Comment: Gracias @SebastiánMiranda intentaré eso!

Comment: @Shaz, si por eso la pregunta, si bien así funciona, no me parece la manera correcta. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví en base al [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54167403/preventing-login-with-laravels-auth) que me pasó @SebastiánMiranda.
En LoginController:

```
    protected function authenticated()
{
    if (auth()->user()->estado =='SUSPENDIDO') {
        auth()->logout();
        return back()
            ->with('info', 'Cuenta suspendida por Administrador');
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

GRACIAS!

Comment: que bueno que te funcionó!!

Comment: Yo preferiría evaluar esto en el middleware, me parece el punto más adecuado, con eso no llega al controlador la solicitud.